# How to keep number displayed when submitting the form to itself

Tags: php, jquery, forms

Below I have an application. Now on the previous page user types in a number and submit the form into this page. The number is then displayed in this page. Now on this page the user submits the form to itself but the problem is that the number would then dissapear. How do I keep the number dispalyed after submitting the form to itself?

```
 <?php
    session_start();
    //validate the post data if necessary
    $_SESSION['sessionNum'] = $_POST['sessionNum'];
    ?>

    <script type="text/javascript">

    function showConfirm(){

         var confirmMsg=confirm("Make sure that your details are correct, once you proceed after this stage you would not be able to go back and change any details towards Questions, Options and Answers for your Session." + "\n" + "\n" + "Are you sure you want to Proceed?" + "\n" );

        if (confirmMsg==true)
        {
            submitform();   
        }
    }

    function submitform()
    {
        var sessionMarksO = document.getElementById("sessionMarks");
          sessionMarksO.submit();

    }
     </script>
     <body>

      <form id="enter" action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="post" onsubmit="return validateForm(this);" >
          <p><input id="submitBtn" name="submitDetails" type="submit" value="Submit Details" onClick="myClickHandler(); return false;" /></p>
     </form> 

    <script type="text/javascript">

    function myClickHandler(){
         if(validation()){
                    showConfirm();
         }
    }

    </script> 

    <?php  
    $outputDetails = "";
    $outputDetails .= "
    <table id='sessionDetails' border='1'>
    <tr>
    <th>Number of Sessions:</th> 
    <th>$_SESSION['sessionNum']</th>
    </tr>";
    $outputDetails .= "</table>";

    echo $outputDetails;
    ?>
```

Comment: Does anyone else not see where to type in a number?

Comment: um....I don't see the input called sessionNum...

Comment: @KyleMacey OP Says on previous page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change :

```
$_SESSION['sessionNum'] = $_POST['sessionNum'];
```

to

```
if (isset($_POST['sessionNum'])) {
   $_SESSION['sessionNum'] = $_POST['sessionNum'];
}
```

this won't reset the `sessionNum` in the session unless you post a form with an input with the name `sessionNum`

Comment: thank you that has worked :) I will mark it as best answer when it lets me in 6 mins

Answer (score 0):

you can use **isset** to see if session exists

```
      $_SESSION['session_num'] = (isset($_SESSION['session_num'])) ? 
             $_SESSION['session_num'] : 
             $_POST['num];
```

Comment: i really would like to know why you think it is not a valid php.

Comment: still missing one .... and why not just have a simple `if` statment - you are setting `$_SESSION['session_num']` to itself if its set !!!

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('form').submit(function(){
    <? if (isset($_POST['sessionNum'])) 
    {   
          $_SESSION['sessionNum'] = $_POST['sessionNum'];
    }
    ? >
}
```

Comment: that isnt going to work - PHP is server side, JavaScript is Client side .... so the PHP will be executed before the form is submitted